# ¿Cómo comparar objetos de un ArrayList en Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

tengo un arraylist el cual tiene un objeto llamado color, donde solo se almacenan dos valores (rojo y negro) y quiero que "si encuentra un color rojo o más se ejecute una acción x"  y si encuentra que todos son color negro ejecute otra acción x y si el objeto es nulo se ejecute una tercera acción x

Intenté esto pero es demasiado limitado, me gustaria que me apoyen con esto, muchas gracias

```
List<AutoResponseDto> auto = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < auto.size(); i++) {
    if (colores.get(i).color.equals("rojo")) {
        // Acción 1
    } else {
        // Acción 2
    }
}
```

**EDITO**

Dejo como lo solucione, con la idea de @amj2020 y la de @Pablo Lozano

```
List<AutoResponseDto> auto = new ArrayList<>();
boolean encontrado = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < auto.size(); x++) {
        AutoResponseDto p = auto.get(x);
        if (p.getColor().equals("rojo")) {
            encontrado = true;
            break; // Termino ciclo, pues ya lo encontramos
        }
    }

   // Al terminar el ciclo compurebo 
    if (encontrado) {
        System.out.println("El color rojo existe");
                 //Accion x
    } else {
        System.out.println("El color rojo NO existe");
                 //Accion x
    }
```

Comment: ¿Donde esta declarado colores? ¿Que tipo es AutoResponseDto? Falta información para poder ayudarte, sube el código por favor

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida para entender cómo hacer una buena pregunta y qué es un [mcve] y por qué es importante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de comprobar que todos los elementos de tu ArrayList son negros es usando streams:

```
boolean todosNegros = colores.stream().allMatch(elem -> elem.color.equals("negro"));
if (todosNegros) {
    ...
}
```

Si no quieres usar streams, entonces necesitas una variable "estado" que indique si se ha encontrado otro color:

```
boolean todosNegros = true;
for (int i = 0; colores.size() > i; i++) {
   if (!colores.get(i).color.equals("negro")) {
       todosNegros = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

boolean existeRojo = colores.contains("Rojo");

boolean existeNegro = colores.contains("Negro");

```
    if (existeRojo ) {
        // Acciones que desees realizar cuando sea rojo
    } else if (existeNegro ){
        // Acciones que desees realizar cuando sea negro
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("El color no existe");
    }
```